# Spring Security Download file instead of login

Tags: java, spring-security

I have spirng app with login form. When i try to loggin with valid username and password it download a file instead of redirect me to the home page.This is my configuration. For example when on defaultSuccessUrl of the login replace "/home" with "/users/register" it work but when i try with "/home" or "/" it downloads a file instead of login. Any ideas why?

```
    package com.example.finalproject.config;`

import com.example.finalproject.model.enums.Roles;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;


@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public ApplicationSecurityConfiguration(
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {

        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                  authorizeRequests().
                  requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll().
                  antMatchers("/", "/users/login", "/users/register").permitAll().
                  antMatchers("/**").authenticated().
                and().
                  formLogin().
                  loginPage("/users/login").
                  usernameParameter(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY).
                  passwordParameter(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY).
                  defaultSuccessUrl("/home").
                  failureForwardUrl("/users/login-error").
                and().
                  logout().
                  logoutUrl("/users/logout").
                  logoutSuccessUrl("/").
                  invalidateHttpSession(true).
                  deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
                userDetailsService(userDetailsService).
                passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing this with `defaultSuccessUrl("/home.html", true) and tell me if it works

Comment: Yes i replaced with defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true) and it works when i replaced with defaultSuccessUrl("/home.html", true) if returned error 404. Thank you :D

Comment: Cool. I've converted my comment to an answer. Please feel free to like and upvote so that it's easier for others to find and reuse it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with `defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true) and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have controller with getmapping tag
@GetMapping(value = "/home")